# validate length only if no image attachement is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make validates_length only occur if no pictures are present but have no clue ...

```
 class Post < ApplicationRecord

     validates_attachment_content_type :pictures, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
     validates_length_of :description, :minimum => 3, :maximum => 200
 end
```

Comment: im quite not understand. Wanna validate picture, must be exist ?

Comment: No sir both are validated above as you see but the thing is if I post an image there is no need for text to be validated and vice versa If I posted text there is no need for image to be validated .. Hope you understand me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not happy using `Proc` but this can be done with `:if` option, like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates_attachment_content_type :pictures, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/, if: Proc.new { |a| a.description.nil? }
  validates_length_of :description, minimum: 3, maximum: 200, if: Proc.new { |a| a.pictures.nil? }
end
```

Comment: thanks this worked but why you don't like Proc.new ? is there any valnurability here ?

Comment: Can't tell you reasonably, but I have internal discomfort using Proc instance for code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a custom validate method and inside you can check both conditions

```
 validate :attachment_or_length

 def attachment_or_length
   content_type = self.try(:pictures).content-type.your_match_method
   desc_size = self.try(:description).size.between?(3,200)

   return if content_type or desc_size // validation passes

   errors.add(:pictures, "Content type doesn't match") unless content_type // fail
   errors.add(:description, "Description size has to be between 3 and 200") unless desc_size // fail
 end
```